# How to delete shooping cart before new add product cart and redirect checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I need to redirect product add to cart button to checkout page instead of cart page

and

also product will delete in cart before new add by custom module.

so how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Redirect after product add to cart:

add one hidden field in product view page with name **return_url**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>" name="return_url"/>
```

Now the page 'll redirect to the checkout onepage after adding the product to cart.

Refer this [controller file](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#l75-l86).